# Append random 2 digits to user input code and add it in file

Tags: python-3.x

Using Python 3, I am trying to write a code which would generate a 11 digit code and add it in text file. In case if the text file already has that code, a new unique code should get generated. I am stuck in the loop logic, whenever I call the Create function, the newly generated ID should be again checked in the file until unique is created and then it should get added in the text file.

```
f2=open("abc.txt","r")
    def Create():
        global ID
        Var1 = str((random.randint(0,9)))
        ID= Userip+Userip+Userip+Var1+Userip   
        print("New ID code : ", ID)

if ID in f2.read():
    print("generate new ID code")
    while i in range(11):
         print("Counter: ",i)
         Create()
         print("Changed ID is: ", ID)
         i=i+1

else:
    f=open("abc.txt", "a")
    f.write("Adding new ID %s\r\n" % ID)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

f2=open("abc.txt","r")

1- The indentation here is wrong:

```
    def Create():
        global ID
        Var1 = str((random.randint(0,9)))
        ID= Userip+Userip+Userip+Var1+Userip   
        print("New ID code : ", ID)
```

It should be:

```
def Create():
        global ID
        Var1 = str((random.randint(0,9)))
        ID= Userip+Userip+Userip+Var1+Userip   
        print("New ID code : ", ID)
```

2- You don't need to loop over the function and call it 11 times to generate only one ID. You can just call it once and increase the random generation range to match your desired number of digits (in your case 10**10 to 10**11).

And your script would be:

import random

```
f2=open("abc.txt","w+")

def Create():
        global ID
        Var1 = str((random.randint(10**10,10**11)))
        ID= Var1
        print("New ID code : ", ID)
        return ID
ID = ''
f2=open("abc.txt","r")

while True:

    if ID in f2.read():
        print("generate new ID code")
        Create()


    else:
        f=open("abc.txt", "a")
        f.write("Adding new ID %s\r\n" % ID)
        f.close()
```

Finally, You must tell your script when to stop. After a certain number of unique generated IDs maybe.

Comment: If my ID is like ABCSIE9955P, once the create function generates new ID it is not getting compared again in file to generate new ID. I need to create a single unique ID only by changing the second last digit and then add it in the text file. The while loop will run infinite times, I need to execute the if loop only when the generated ID exists in the file, else it should goto else loop when the unique ID is created by create function.